# Why does my app crash when I press a button and how to fix it

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a basic dice roller for a card game. It is on the second screen of two. The screen opens fine when I press the button to open it, but when I click the dice button the app simply crashes. I am using the newest version of Android Studio. Here's my code:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.Random;
import static android.R.attr.value;

public class Extras extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener{

    Button btn1;
    TextView numberGenerator;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_extras);


        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.diceButton);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
        numberGenerator = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.numberGenerator);

    }


    @Override

    public void onClick(View v) {
        int min = 1;
        int max = 6;
        Random random = new Random();
        int value = random.nextInt(max - min) + min;
        numberGenerator.setText(value+"");

        if (v == btn1) {
            numberGenerator.setText(value);
        }

    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Usually when an application "crashes" it shows an error message or exception message. If yours does this, you will want to share this with us.

Comment: a useful read for a new android dev http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Answer (score 2):

Your app is crashes because you are trying to put int value to the setText() method.

Here:

```
if (v == btn1) {
    numberGenerator.setText(value);
}
```

Try instead:

```
if (v == btn1) {
    numberGenerator.setText(String.valueOf(value));
}
```

If this does not work post your stacktrace.

Comment: I would think this is a compiler kind of complaint

Comment: this answers it. `setText` is overloaded to take an `int` resource identifier, so you can't just pass any old `int` into it. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(int)